# Conditional Operator in F# (A?B:C)

Tags: c#, f#, conditional-operator

In C#, we have the conditional operator:

```
[condition] ? [value if true] : [value if false]
```

But I can't seem to find this in F#. Does it exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As found [here](https://lorgonblog.wordpress.com/2008/11/28/what-does-this-c-code-look-like-in-f-part-one-expressions-and-statements/) the answer is

> C# has the ternary operator "?:" for conditional expressions:
>
> ```
> condition ? trueVal : falseVal
> ```
>
> F# has the same operator, but its name is if-then-else:
>
> ```
> if condition then trueVal else falseVal
> ```
>
> (Note that "if" is used much less frequently in F# than in C#; in F#, many conditionalexpressions are done via pattern-matching rather than if-then-else.)

The website I linked offers a bunch of C# vs F# examples.

Comment: Essentially, in F#, many things you may think of as statements are expressions and able to return a value.